# Azure AD B2C Cordova iOS: "We are having trouble signing you in"

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using Azure B2C to authenticate an Ionic app. 
I've implemented the code flow with Cordova's `InAppBrowser`.
Everything works fine on Android, but iOS gives me

> We are having trouble signing you in

The redirect URL is `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`. 
Am I missing something?

Comment: it might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http

Try setting this in your plist and try

Comment: Same error, but I'm using HTTPs so I find the problem is somewhere else

Comment: Could you implement ad-b2c social login with ionic/cordova? For me nothing happens when i tap on social button.... the logic works fine in a web app